# Reopened pop window on browser reload:

Tags: javascript, php

`openerWindow.php` will call `openedWindow.html` through a button , but why when i close `openedWindow.html` and refresh the browser this `openedWindow` is shown up again?? isn't this popup window just triggered through the button. I can't figure it out, why and how to solve this :

***openerWindow.php***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="open" value="open pop up" onclick=""/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["open"])){ // if button clicked call other html page as pop up

?>
    <script >
    newWindow = window.open('openedWindow.html', 'formUntukUpte', 'width=400,height=350');


   </script>
<?php
}
?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***openedWindow.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate your help ,,

Comment: `unset($_POST["open"])` right inside your `if()`

Comment: When you refresh openerWindow.php, does the browser ask you something (if yes you may be sending the form again) ? Instead of pressing F5 try to copy and paste the URL of openerWindow.php in the browser and see if the popup open again

Comment: Chrome said when i reload (after closing  opened window) = "
 ....... Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue??"
 ". I have no idea brothers.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the browser is probably preserving the post data.

You can check by adding `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`to your page and you will see if the post data is still there.

It seems like this would be easier to do in javascript:

```
<button onclick="window.open('openedWindow.html', 'formUntukUpte', 'width=400,height=350')">Open Popup</button>
```

If you need to do it in PHP then you would need to store a value in a session var, something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['open'] && !isset($_SESSION['popup_shown'])) {
$_SESSION['popup_shown'] = true;
?>
<script>
//popup launch
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: it's still there! how i reset this one (this array), I get no clue how to disable di resubmission.

Comment: yes it's still there, so how to solve it i get no clue at all.

Comment: when the browser says "Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?" it means that it will resend the post data if you click "yes"

Comment: so how to prevent this re-submission (by default), i meant user don't need to set any of configuration in browser??